# How to filter suggestion users by interest in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-scripts

I working on social network site in that I have 3 SQL table to search users for suggestion. 
for ex: user have must choose one category at registration time.

User Table:

```
userID   | username   | categoryID  | createdOn 
101          abc           2           20-07-11
```

..... like wise

Category Table

```
  CategoryID   | CategoryName
       0              Health
       1              IT
       2              Construction
```

..... like wise

and another table is interest Category,
User must choose at most 5 interest like shown below

InterestCategories

```
UserInterestID   |   UserID    | location  |    CategoryID    | CreatedBy
0                     101          India           1             101
1                     101          UK              3             101    
2                     101          CA              10            101
3                     101          RA              14            101
4                     510          LA              5             510
```

Now I want to get user order by

1. User's from Interest category
2. Users from my own category

How We get all suggestion users as per above condition using SQL Server 2005 script?

Answer (score 0):

For #1, please try:

```
select u.* from User u, InterestCategories i where u.UserID = i.UserID and i.CategoryID = %InterestCatagoryID%;
```

For #2, please try:

```
select u.* from User u, InterestCategories i, User m where u.UserID = i.UserID and i.CategoryID = m.CatetoryID and m.UserID = %MyUserID%;
```

Comment: Hello i want to both point should be in one query not separate query